# python, read inside dict value as single value without "[" and "]"

Tags: python, dictionary

in my python script

```
>>>var1={'AZ_BINARY': ['im\\build\\ks\\in\\AAAAA\\az.o'], 'AP_BINARY': ['LINUX\\project\\platform\\em.o'], 'BOOT': ['trust\\build\\bin\\AAAA\\t.o'], 'T_BINARY': ['boot\\ build\\ms\\bin\\9900\\sbl1.mbn']}
>>>print var1[BOOT] 
['trust\\build\\bin\\AAAA\\t.o']
```

is there a way to print it without [' and '] without using any trim function?

Comment: Perhaps you don't want a list in the first place?  You could consider removing the `[]` in the dictionary definition.  It doesn't seem like you are using them as lists here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The returned value is a list, so index it:

```
>>> print var1[BOOT][0]
trust\build\bin\AAAA\t.o
```

Answer (score 1):

sure, you are printing a list with one element. You can print the first element like so.

```
>>>var1={'AZ_BINARY': ['im\\build\\ks\\in\\AAAAA\\az.o'], 'AP_BINARY': ['LINUX\\project\\platform\\em.o'], 'BOOT': ['trust\\build\\bin\\AAAA\\t.o'], 'T_BINARY': ['boot\\ build\\ms\\bin\\9900\\sbl1.mbn']}
>>>print var1[BOOT][0]
```

`'trust\\build\\bin\\AAAA\\t.o'`